# Java make a button in JPanel // Basic Question

Tags: java, forms, button, jframe, jpanel

So how do i make a button in my JPanel i am really noob and can't seem to find it.
My Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Casino");
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setContentPane(new Paneel());
}
```

My JPanel

```
public class Paneel extends JPanel {
JPanel paneel = new JPanel();
JButton test = new JButton("test");
paneel.add(test); 
}
```

i also have an basic question. The 'big people' do they make their layout directly from a **.form** file or do they actually write everything them self where to stand and such cz the drag drop seems easier or is it not the way to do it?. What i mean is this: [Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWdKP.png)

Comment: You should follow the official tutorials for this kind of thing. They're generally good. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html

Comment: *"The 'big people' do they make their layout directly from a .form file or do they actually write everything them self where to stand and such cz the drag drop seems easier or is it not the way to do it?"* - 99.9% of my time is spent hand writing UIs.  Form editors are to easy at introducing laziness, are to difficult to manage from an extension point of view, lock you into a single IDE use case and are generally best avoided.  There are times where I might use a IDE to just get the rough idea out and then I convert it to hand code, but that's me.

Comment: SO is not a replacement for good tutorials, blogs and effort. Your "need" is not an uncommon one and has been well answered, in a verity of different mediums.  You'd be better first researching the issue before posting

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question would be better answered reading one of the many, readily available tutorials, like [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: You can create a `JPanel`, add a `JButton` to it. Then, add the panel to the `JFrame`. Or, you can add the button to the `JFrame` directly. You can try various ways and see how things work. Also, try searching the net (Google) with something like _"Java Swing how to create buttons within a JPanel"_, etc. In case if you are using an IDE, there are IDE specific _help_ and _tutorials_ on the net.